# React Router | call function on private router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). In that I have to call function on a `private router`

**Route**

```
<Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Spin spinning={this.props.isloading}>
            <Switch>>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Spin>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            this.validateSession()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

Can I call function `this.validateSession()`? It shows type error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass down validate function

```
<Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Spin spinning={this.props.isloading}>
            <Switch>>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute validate={this.validateSession.bind(this)} path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Spin>
        </div>
      </Router>



export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, validate, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            validate()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

Comment: It is not redirecting page. It is keep on calling the same function

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the validate as prop to the PrivateRoute component

```
<PrivateRoute path="/Dashboard" validate={this.validateSession} component={Dashboard} />
```

and your component would look like:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, validate, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            validate()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```